# ImageView in SplashScreen is not showing

Tags: android

I am very new to android and trying to add a splash screen I am half way succeeded. But a weird think happening that surely an easy one. here i have tried :-

I wanted to stop the SplashScreen for some time. This splash screen layout contain a ImageView that show the appLogo.

```
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);

        ImageView splashScreenImage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.appLogo);
        splashScreenImage.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.splLogo);

        Thread.Sleep(30000);

        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

Actualy my splash screen waiting stopping for some time but `ImageView` is not showing it come out at the last moment when new activity is going to start.

Why is this happening ? any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
Thread.Sleep(30000);
```

It is not showing because you are blocking your UI thread to process the `SetContentView` to display in the screen thus it is not showing.

What it is really doing is that it will wait for 30 second without the display/black screen and change activity.

**Solution:**

Use a timer or Handler instead of sleeping the thread.